# Why I see only the textview on the phone but not the seekbar?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

the application is running and working fine except the seekbar value and the textview part.

before adding the textview I saw the seekbar but now I see only the textview.
I'm trying to assign the seekbar value to counter and then to display counter in the textview.

I want to see the value of the seekbar each time I'm changing it's value in the textview.

the design:

[image: design]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="355dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="191dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.flashlight

import android.content.Context
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.widget.SeekBar
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlin.math.log

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var flashLightStatus: Boolean = false
    var flashLightOn = false
    var counter = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        val seek = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar)
        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
                override fun onProgressChanged(
                    seekBar: SeekBar?,
                    progress: Int,
                    fromUser: Boolean
                ) {
                    // Log.d("seekbar", "Your Progress: ${seekBar?.progress}"

                    counter = progress
                    textView.text = counter.toString()
                }

                override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) = Unit
                override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) = Unit
            },
        )

        startFlashLight()

    }


    private fun openFlashLight() {
        val cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList[0]
        if (!flashLightStatus) {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true)
                flashLightStatus = true

            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false)
                flashLightStatus = false
            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        }
    }

    private fun closeFlashLight()
    {
        val cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList[0]
        if (flashLightStatus) {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false)
                flashLightStatus = false

            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true)
                flashLightStatus = true
            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            }
        }
    }

    fun startFlashLight() {
        openFlashLight()
        flashLightOn = true

        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        handler.postDelayed(object: Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                if (flashLightOn) {
                    closeFlashLight()
                } else {
                    openFlashLight()
                }

                // Changing the toggle and calling the same Runnable again after 5 seconds
                flashLightOn = !flashLightOn
                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000)
            }
        }, 5000)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it look OK in the XML file's preview? Those huge margins you're using in the two views could cause some issues on certain sizes and shapes of screens. You might want to introduce spacing into your ConstraintLayout as a more natural and forgiving way to handle it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 working. I changed the textview top margin to 100.  I will keep playing with it later but now it's working.  thanks.